# solving a exception in jonas As 5.2.1 deployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, osgi, persistence-unit

I am newbie in develloping with JOnAs platform, also in Spring and more genrally in web
 devellopments. After having somte troubles with JBoss 5.1.GA and tomcat 6.x,7.x i decided to
 move to jonas. I 'm now facing an issue in the deployment of my web application. The given
 stack trace is the following :

2011-08-25 04:56:04,467 : JPersistenceUnitInfoLoader.loadPersistenceUnitInfoImplList : No SharedCacheMode defined. Set to default UNSPECIFIED
2011-08-25 04:56:04,474 : BaseModelMBean.invoke : Exception invoking method deploy
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/SharedCacheMode
    at org.ow2.easybeans.persistence.xml.JPersistenceUnitInfoLoader.loadPersistenceUnitInfoImplList(JPersistenceUnitInfoLoader.java:233)
    at org.ow2.easybeans.persistence.xml.JPersistenceUnitInfoHelper.getPersistenceUnitInfoList(JPersistenceUnitInfoHelper.java:118)
    at org.ow2.easybeans.persistence.xml.PersistenceXmlFileAnalyzer.analyzePersistenceXmlFile(PersistenceXmlFileAnalyzer.java:130)
    at org.ow2.jonas.ejb.easybeans.EasyBeansService._*getPersistenceUnitManager(EasyBeansService.java:880)
    at org.ow2.jonas.ejb.easybeans.EasyBeansService.getPersistenceUnitManager(EasyBeansService.java)
    at org.ow2.jonas.web.base.BaseWebContainerService.registerWar(BaseWebContainerService.java:821)
    at org.ow2.jonas.web.base.BaseWebContainerService.registerWar(BaseWebContainerService.java:1241)
    at org.ow2.jonas.web.base.proxy.HttpOnDemandProxy.addWar(HttpOnDemandProxy.java:352)
    at org.ow2.jonas.web.base.WARDeployer.doDeploy(WARDeployer.java:70)
    at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer$1.execute(AbsDeployer.java:96)
    at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer$1.execute(AbsDeployer.java:95)
    at org.ow2.util.execution.helper.RunnableHelper.execute(RunnableHelper.java:77)
    at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.AbsDeployer.deploy(AbsDeployer.java:94)
    at org.ow2.util.ee.deploy.impl.deployer.DeployerManager.deploy(DeployerManager.java:129)
    at org.ow2.jonas.lib.jmbeans.J2EEServer.*_deploy(J2EEServer.java:823)
    at org.ow2.jonas.lib.jmbeans.J2EEServer.deploy(J2EEServer.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:458)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:857)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:795)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1450)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:90)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1285)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1383)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:807)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.SharedCacheMode not found by org.ow2.jonas.osgi.javaee-api [48]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.getClassByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.resolver.WireImpl.getClass(WireImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.searchImports(ModuleImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:722)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 42 more
2011-08-25 04:57:46,777 : J2EEServer._*undeploy : Cannot undeploy the deployable 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Archive 'WARDeployableImpl[archive=/home/stephane/projetJEE/server/jonas-full-5.2.0/base/archives/immo.war]'  is not deployed.
    at org.ow2.jonas.lib.jmbeans.J2EEServer.*_undeploy(J2EEServer.java:842)
    at org.ow2.jonas.lib.jmbeans.J2EEServer.undeploy(J2EEServer.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:458)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:857)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:795)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1450)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:90)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1285)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1383)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:807)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
2011-08-25 04:57:46,778 : BaseModelMBean.invoke : Exception invoking method undeploy
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot undeploy the deployable 'WARDeployableImpl[archive=/home/stephane/projetJEE/server/jonas-full-5.2.0/base/archives/immo.war]' : Archive 'WARDeployableImpl[archive=/home/stephane/projetJEE/server/jonas-full-5.2.0/base/archives/immo.war]'  is not deployed.
    at org.ow2.jonas.lib.jmbeans.J2EEServer.__undeploy(J2EEServer.java:849)
    at org.ow2.jonas.lib.jmbeans.J2EEServer.undeploy(J2EEServer.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.commons.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:458)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:857)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:795)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1450)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:90)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1285)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1383)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:807)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

I hope someone migth help me. I have tried to launch (not at the same time, but as i couldn't acheive succesfully one i move to the other) correctly one of the following application server for 2 weeks. I am using **Jonas 5.2.x full profile**.
Good bye

Answer (score 1):

What is the persistence provider used ? Check JONAS_BASE/conf/jonas.properties and if hibernate is set, change it to hibernate3.5 so you can have a JPA 2 persistence provider

Answer (score 0):

What does NoClassDefFoundError normally mean to you?

```
NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/SharedCacheMode
```

Likely down to not having a JPA2 API jar in your classpath when something else (JoNAS) is expecting it.